# MVC5 cookieless session Id is not authenticated in different browser, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a new MVC5 web page using cookieless in the web.config. I use the ASP Identity to log into the application via the default template login form.

My url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:48839/(S(wjz4mdav4ue0osbywkol0zuv))/Home/
```

I logged in using Chrome. Copying the url to Edge or Firefox, to my surprise, didn't log me in. I don't see my username and so on...

`Request.IsAuthenticated` is `false` in Edge and Firefox.

How does MVC authenticate the user? Does it use the Browser's User agent string?

I remember doing this a couple of years ago (maybe MVC3?) this did work.

Edit:
This is the entry in my web.config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

I also noticed that using incognito mode in Chrome has the same behavior.

Comment: could you show how you have set this up in your web,config please?

Comment: I edited my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx#Anchor_0):

> ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during
>   a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist
>   variable values for the duration of that session.

That means session state will be different for different browser, and that new session will get its own SessionId, which is passed in URL in your case and not in cookies

There is another thing is regenerating expired sessionIds:

> By default, the session ID values that are used in cookieless sessions are recycled. That is, if a request is made with a session ID that has expired, a new session is started by using the SessionID value that is supplied with the request. This can result in a session unintentionally being shared when a link that contains a cookieless SessionID value is used by multiple browsers. (This can occur if the link is passed through a search engine, through an e-mail message, or through another program.) You can reduce the chance of session data being shared by configuring the application not to recycle session identifiers. To do this, set the regenerateExpiredSessionId attribute of the sessionState configuration element to true. This generates a new session ID when a cookieless session request is made with an expired session ID.

You can try setting `regenerateExpiredSessionId` to false, taking into account possible downsides.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @DoubleVoid I'm glad that helped. Thank you too!